# find p such that the series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Find all value of $p$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^∞ (\frac{1}{n}$  - sin $\frac{1}{n})^p$ convergen

I get the answes for $p>2$ but I'm not sure this is all the solutions of this question

Answer (score 2):

First of all, notice that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\cfrac{\frac1n-\sin\frac1n}{\frac1{n^3}}=\frac16$$

Thus, by limit comparison test, we need only to consider whether the following converges:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)^p=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^{3p}}$$

And by p-series, it converges for $p>1/3$.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cfrac{\frac1n-\sin\frac1n}{\frac1{n^2}}=0$ . I try this but maybe there is $p$ other then your answer for example $p>1/4$

Comment: @lio It should be $n^3$ in the very bottom.  And there shouldn't be any other possible values of $p$.

Comment: how can you believe it?

Comment: @lio By the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).  If and only if the second series converges will the first one converge.

Comment: i know by the limit comparison this is true but. But how can you believe that this is not true for example $p>1/4$. I get the answer is $p>1/2$ previosly but your answer more better than my answer because$1/3$ is than$1/2$ . Can you give a reason for $p>1/4% the series doesn't convergen?

Comment: @lio Because if the second series diverges, the first diverges.  That is the "if and only if" part.